In Proteus 8 how do I know if current on a component is too high?

This kind of setup should at least warn me about the current on the LED being too high. When I'm going to build something in real life, how can I be sure I don't need resistors here and there? Maybe there is some setting in the program that will turn on that kind of notification?

LEDs always need a device that will limit (set) the current. Thus, you always need to have a resistor in series with the LED.

I know, it's just that in this simple case, it is very easy to see, but what of some more complex circuits? In some cases, those problems can be hard to spot and I hoped I could rely on the software to warn me about that.

No, the software will not warn about it. The simulator software does not take into account that the maximum parameters of the component used were exceeded. This is your job.

This is why electrical engineers still have jobs over some computer designing everything.

This is why data sheets are available for products. Regarding the LED, data sheets have information on maximum current, light output versus current, forward voltage versus current, thermal data, ... From this information you can design the circuit. You'll need to consider how the devices are mounted, heat sink performance, ambient temperature, heat from other components, ...

Well, I guess there is value in simulating just the logic of circuit components. I just hoped the simulation software would take care of that too. Like, the IDE would take care of undeclared variable or something.
